# Find if network interface is a virtual device in AIX

Tags: networking, network-interface, aix

In Linux we can use /sys/devices/virtual/net/<if_name> if the if_name is present under the directory, the device is virtual.

In AIX do we have any way to check if an interface say en0 or lo0 is virtual or physical?
Is it possible to lsdev with specific parameters to get list of virtual network devices on AIX or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are on an AIX LPAR (not a VIOS) you most probably have virtual devices, not a physical card. Also, "lo0" is the loopback interface and per definition virtual.

Having said this, you can use the command `lsdev -c adapter`
to get a list of all entries in the class "adapter". These are network and disk adapters as well (and a few other adapters too, but these are the most common), so a possible output could look like this:

```
# lsdev -c adapter
ent0   Available       Virtual I/O Ethernet Adapter (l-lan)
fcs0   Available 20-T1 Virtual Fibre Channel Client Adapter
fcs1   Available 21-T1 Virtual Fibre Channel Client Adapter
fcs2   Available 22-T1 Virtual Fibre Channel Client Adapter
fcs3   Available 23-T1 Virtual Fibre Channel Client Adapter
vsa0   Available       LPAR Virtual Serial Adapter
```

You can also list the interfaces by listing the class "if", like this:

```
# lsdev -c if
en0 Available  Standard Ethernet Network Interface
et0 Defined    IEEE 802.3 Ethernet Network Interface
lo0 Available  Loopback Network Interface
```

To get more info about one of these interfaces use the `lsattr` command:

```
# lsattr -El en0
alias4                      IPv4 Alias including Subnet Mask              True
alias6                      IPv6 Alias including Prefix Length            True
arp           on            Address Resolution Protocol (ARP)             True
authority                   Authorized Users                              True
broadcast                   Broadcast Address                             True
monitor       off           Enable/Disable monitor for virtual Ethernet   True
mtu           1500          Maximum IP Packet Size for This Device        True
mtu_bypass    on            Enable/Disable largesend for virtual Ethernet True
netaddr       xxx.xx.xx.xx  Internet Address                              True
netaddr6                    IPv6 Internet Address                         True
netmask       255.255.255.0 Subnet Mask                                   True
prefixlen                   Prefix Length for IPv6 Internet Address       True
remmtu        576           Maximum IP Packet Size for REMOTE Networks    True
rfc1323       1             Enable/Disable TCP RFC 1323 Window Scaling    True
security      none          Security Level                                True
state         up            Current Interface Status                      True
tcp_mssdflt                 Set TCP Maximum Segment Size                  True
tcp_nodelay                 Enable/Disable TCP_NODELAY Option             True
tcp_recvspace 262144        Set Socket Buffer Space for Receiving         True
tcp_sendspace 262144        Set Socket Buffer Space for Sending           True
thread        off           Enable/Disable thread attribute               True
```